# Can I name files recursively in Stata?

Tags: loops, recursion, stata

I am creating 1 test file for each year from 2001 to 2010. I define some variables for my 2001 file, and then, from 2002 onwards, I want Stata to merge it with the file from the previous year.
My minimum working example looks like this:

```
set obs 100
g year=2001
g casenum=_n
g yob=1973
save file_2001, replace

forv n=2002(1)2010{
clear
set obs 110
g casenum=_n
g year=`n'
merge 1:1 casenum using file_`n-1', keepusing (yob)
save file_`n', replace
}
```

The error I get is file_2002.dta not found. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing recursive here, just plain iteration or looping.  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
merge 1:1 casenum using file_`n-1', keepusing (yob)
```

There is no local macro named n-1. This should be  `` `=`n'-1' ``